# Does Derby supports INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY statements?

Tags: java, database, derby

Does anyone knows whether Derby supports INSERT IGNORE or ON DUPLICATE KEY statements? If yes, please provide a link describing how to use it.
Thanks so much.

Comment: You can catch the duplicate key exception and ignore it in your code.

Comment: If then, can I do with batchUpdate() of JDBC? Is it allowable to catch an error update in the batch?